# electron webview not getting focused from another webview

Tags: electron

I have multiple WebViews in my Electron app, I want focus first WebView's element when `ctrl+f` is pressed. 
I have managed that but when I am in another WebView my element get focused but I am not able to type anything from that WebView I have to compulsory go to first WebView then it works.

Am I on wrong way or something else?

Note: (I have single browser window and all WebViews are placed in it)

Comment: The text was distracting to read because every word was capitalized, fixed.

Comment: sorry ! @SurvivalMachine i will keep in mind. Thanks